Password leak in MemoryDump from Java File which uses Java.io.Console
I got this code adapted from the official Java-Tutorial Page Console - Java Tutorial
public class RedirectOutputStreamExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Console c = System.console();
        if (c == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String login = ((Console) c).readLine("Enter your login: ");
        char [] oldPassword = c.readPassword("Enter your old password: ");

        if (verify(login, oldPassword)) {
            boolean noMatch;
            do {
                char [] newPassword1 = c.readPassword("Enter your new password: ");
                char [] newPassword2 = c.readPassword("Enter new password again: ");
                noMatch = ! Arrays.equals(newPassword1, newPassword2);
                if (noMatch) {
                    c.format("Passwords don't match. Try again.%n");
                } else {
                    c.format("Password for %s changed.%n", login);
                }
                Arrays.fill(newPassword1, ' ');
                Arrays.fill(newPassword2, ' ');
                System.out.println("password is: "+newPassword1);
                System.out.println("password is: "+newPassword2);
            } while (noMatch);
        }
        Arrays.fill(oldPassword, ' ');
        System.out.println(oldPassword);
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }
}

After the three passwords have been overwritten, they are printed out as empty lines (as expected).  As you see:

(I had to do it in the console cause the IntelliJ terminal had security problems and threw the error "no Console")
However, after the program was halted, a memory dump was created using jmap and the process ID.

My entered password was still visible in the memory dump as you see:

How is that possible? Did I do something wrong? Is there a weak default security configuration in my JVM?
I asked ChatGPT and it suggests that console uses Strings in its internal operations.

Only addressing side-issue in this comment:
the console object is expected to be null from within an IDE - see also here.

What does the method change do?

Also, Java garbage collectors can move objects around in memory, including arrays, so it is entirely possible if that happened, that the old memory location still contains a copy of data even if you cleared it (that is, after it was moved). In short, you cannot rely on clearing an array for getting rid of the data from memory.

@MarkRotteveel the method is a dummy method and returns always true. it's from the oracle tutorial site. i just forgott to remove it from the code

@MarkRotteveel If that is the case, how can we ensure that the input data is cleared after input?

You can't, basically. Clearing it is better than not clearing it, but as I said, it is not guaranteed to work in the face of garbage collectors moving data around.

I repeated those Steps above almost 20 Times, and every time i could see my password in the memory dump.  I can't imagine that it was due to the Garbage Collector moving data every single time. Alltough i would mean that secure login in java would not be possible

It might be worse than you think. I don't know. But, could the password you saw in the heap dump be not for char [] newPassword1 or for char [] newPassword1, but for the System.console Object?

What about the verify method?  Could it be holding a copy of the password?

@OldDogProgrammer As far as I can tell from the code, the console implementation of readPassword() also does its best to eliminate the characters from buffers, but of course, that doesn't guarantee it isn't in some lower-level buffer.

As long as you have no clue what change() is doing, it is definitely possible that a String instance of your char array was created somewhere, and that this String can be found in a heapdump. If you are really that paranoid that this may not happen, you should use the J9 JVM; it will not dump the values to a regular heap dump.
To avoid that the clear text of any password is kept somewhere in memory, you should hash the passwords immediately after getting them and do all the further steps only with the hashes – given that change() would work with that, too, or that you can re-implement it.
Otherwise, from the screenshot of the heapdump, I would say that it would be difficult to identify the string as the password without knowing the password.
